# TortoiseHg won't ignore properly

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, glob, hgignore

I'm fairly new to Tortoise Hg, but it seems that what I want to do is possible. In my repository, I have 4 project folders, each of which contains a bin folder. To minimize the size of the push, I'd like to ignore any files in **any** bin folder (or any subdirectory!).

After searching around, I found that I needed to use a .hgignore in the root of the repo. The forum even provided code to do exactly what I wanted... or so it seemed. Alas, not matter what I try, files in the bin folder still show up in my commit window. I've recreated the .htignore file multiple times, both with TortoiseHg's tool and manually, I've tried both syntaxes, and I've tried all kinds of variations on my patterns.

Here are some I've tried (Using glob syntax. The regexp are similar) .

```
bin/
bin\
bin/*
bin\*
/bin
\bin
/bin/
\bin\
/bin/*
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/bin/** in glob pattern (if files untracked, if they already versioned: `hg forget` before adding to hgignore)

Comment: A slight variation of that worked well. If I used a slash in front, I got an invalid path error.

Answer (score 1):

Noticed this on a Windows machine. Even though `bin/` was listed in `.hgignore`, `hg status` continued to show files in the `bin` directory (none of which were added to the repo).

It turned out that the `.hgignore` that I pulled from the remote repository had Mac-style **line endings**. Changing the file to have [unix-style line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2889181/905908) fixed the issue.